# Using GPG to decrypt Symantec PGP encrypted files?

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, gpg, pgp

Is this possible? I had an old HD encrypted with Symantec PGP. I attempted to decrypt the disk with Symantec's boot time recovery tool. It stalled 18% in, I let it sit for 16 hours, and the machine would no longer boot.

I was able to recover the home directory and copy that to another machine however all of the files are encrypted. I don't have Symantec PGP on this new Linux machine, but I do have GPG installed. Is there a way to decrypt the old files? I have the correct passphrase and I believe I have the keyrings still.

Comment: Please do not cross post your Q across the various SE sites: http://superuser.com/questions/642635/recovering-symantec-wde-encrypted-files-with-gpg

Answer (score 2):

I searched and did not come up with any method that would allow you to do this using GPG. The recommended method is outlined in this thread, titled: [PGP WDE - Restore MBR or get data from an encrypted disk](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/pgp-wde-restore-mbr-or-get-data-encrypted-disk). It's suggested that you use the [WDE Recovery CD](http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH149679).

#### GPGTools

I found on the support forum the following question:

> I'm currently forced to use PGP desktop, and as it turns out, it will
>   prevent my mac from suspending to disk (i.e. hibernating), so I'm
>   looking for alternative full disk encryption tools (after I've
>   formatted my HD because our security dept. has disabled the Decrypt
>   option of my PGP Desktop). So, does GPGTools support
>   suspend-to-disk/hibernate?

To which the answer was:

> unfortunately GPGTools doesn't support full disk encryption at this
>   point. You're stuck with the Symantec people :(

So I would conclude that the GPG tool can not do this.

#### References

- [Troubleshooting: PGP Whole Disk Encryption Recovery](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH149345)
- [PGP WDE - Restore MBR or get data from an encrypted disk](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/pgp-wde-restore-mbr-or-get-data-encrypted-disk)